# Blocking Wayback Machine with robots.txt only works for www.domain.com and NOT for domain.com

Tags: robots.txt

I'm trying to block the Wayback Machine (archive.org) from archving my website and to delete old pages from the archive.

I've added this to my robots.txt, which is placed in the root directory (I'm on Plesk so that will be httpdocs/ ):

```
User-agent: ia_archiver
Disallow: /
```

Now the weird thing is... this only works for WWW.domain.com and not for domain.com. I'm not using the www domain and all www request are redirected to domain.com for seo reasons. So the www.domain.com is now blocked from archving, but domain.com is still being archived.

Am i missing something?

Comment: How do you know/test that it’s still being archived? Did you saw in your logs that their bot accessed documents after it visited the updated robots.txt?

Comment: This looks like a bug. The beta (https://web-beta.archive.org/) handles this correctly: both www.domain.com and domain.com are blocked when instructed to do so by robots.txt. However when using the regular wayback machine (https://archive.org/web/), the www.domain.com gets blocked while the domain.com does not. Were you able to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be a synchronization issue.

While the www.domain.com gets blocked almost immediately after being instructed to do so by robots.txt, the domain.com requires a few hours to a couple of days before honoring the exclusion.

The beta (https://web-beta.archive.org/) handles this correctly: both www.domain.com and domain.com get blocked straight away.